# Find $f(0)$ if $f(x)= \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n-2}}{(2n+1)!} $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

> Find $f(0)$ if $f(x)= \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n-2}}{(2n+1)!} $

This seems trivial but I am not able to figure it out. Do I directly put $x=0$ or should I reindex $n=0$ and use Taylor Theorem. If I use Taylor theorem, then is $f(0)$ simply the $n$ part of the numerator?

Comment: $$f(0) = \frac{-1}{3!} =  \frac{1}{6} $$

Comment: @ILoveMath Both = signs in your comment are wrong...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n-2}}{(2n+1)!}=\frac{1}{3!}-\frac{x^2}{5!}+\cdots$$

Comment: Again... I fail to see how the 5040 coefficient is relevant to the question (even 120 is not...).

Answer (score 2):

For $n\ge 2$ the summand is equal to zero, so you need only to consider the term for $n=1$ $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n-2}}{(2n+1)!} =\frac{1}{(2\cdot1+1)!}+ \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n-2}}{(2n+1)!}=\frac1{3!}+0=\frac16$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $x^3f(x)=x-\sin x=\frac{x^3}{3!}-\frac{x^5}{5!}+...$

Divide by $x^3$ !

Comment: Why multiply and divide by $x^3$? The $x^0$ term is apparent in the original series...

Comment: My intention: the connection between $f$ and $\sin x$

Comment: Yes, this connection exists and it is offtopic. Hence, mentioning it can make for a remark (and an interesting one), not an answer (especially not a full answer).